# Hadoop - where to put global Java flags

Tags: java, macos, hadoop, headless

I need to add the `-Djava.awt.headless=true` to ALL of Hadoop's Java processes. Otherwise, the process is killed for trying to access the window server.

I have tried *everywhere* and cannot find where these flags should be applied. I've managed to get it running for most of the base processes, but one process is eluding me. That process is **MRAppMaster**.

No matter what I do, **MRAppMaster** runs *without* the headless flag. The documentation, being as horrific as it is, has nothing to say about this as far as I can tell.

If there's a location this flag can be applied, I would appreciate it. I'm running Hadoop 2.2.0 on Mac OS 10.9.

Comment: Do you mean to share some flags between mapper or reducer processes of an MR job?

Comment: @AnkurShanbhag I mean to make sure that the flags are set where they need to be. For the next _step_ in the debug process, I need to set the flags for MRAppMaster. But if I can set global flags, it'll ensure I don't have to worry about missing a process. If I do, the Java window server bug will cause it to fail whenever it tries to launch anything without that flag.

Comment: Huh? Hadoop and Swing/AWT?

Comment: @Chiron Hadoop uses AWT, so by default it'll always try to connect to the window server. That's why I need to disable it. But until I find where to put the flag, I can't, and it always fails to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MRAppMaster is YARN-specific.  Anyway, you can pass java opts to the application master through a property called `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts`. You can set it in the map reduce config file, `mapred-site.xml` (and *not*`yarn-site.xml`, as one may guess).

From [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml#yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts):

> **yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts**
>
> Java opts for the MR App Master processes.

Comment: Thank you! If only there was some decent documentation... :(